# Is what the compile issue telling me wrong?

Tags: java

the below is the code I made for a codingbat problem. I think my code looks fine. the problem is below:

When squirrels get together for a party, they like to have cigars. A squirrel party is successful when the number of cigars is between 40 and 60, inclusive. Unless it is the weekend, in which case there is no upper bound on the number of cigars. Return true if the party with the given values is successful, or false otherwise.

cigarParty(30, false) → false
cigarParty(50, false) → true
cigarParty(70, true) → true

it keeps saying compile issue, "(" expected at line 6. Am i doing something wrong that I can't see?

```
public boolean cigarParty(int cigars, boolean isWeekend) {

  if (cigars>=40 || cigars <= 60 && isWeekend){
    return true;

  } if else(cigars<40){
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `else if` not `if else` Compiler is warning on no `(` following an `if` statement.

Comment: `if else` is wrong you should correct it to `else if`

Comment: `if else` should be `else if`

Comment: Since the last two branches both return false, there is no point in having them, or using a conditional statement at all. Simply: `return cigars>=40 || cigars <= 60 && isWeekend;` does the same. But the `cigars <= 60` is true if `cigars >= 40` is false, so you can use `return cigars >= 40 || isWeekend;`. Note that this doesn't meet the requirements, though. Think about which operators you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`if else` is wrong you should correct it to `else if`. This is the correct code :

```
public boolean cigarParty(int cigars, boolean isWeekend) {

  if (cigars>=40 || cigars <= 60 && isWeekend){
    return true;

  }else if(cigars<40){
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `if else`, you have to use `else if`.

```
public boolean cigarParty(int cigars, boolean isWeekend) {

  if (cigars>=40 || cigars <= 60 && isWeekend){
    return true;

  }else if(cigars<40){
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```